# Can only get copy to clipboard on second click

Tags: javascript, php, clipboard.js

#### What I'm doing

I'm using [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/) to copy a URL to the clipboard.

So I start by rendering some HTML in PHP. The code looks something like this:

```
$copyToClipboard = "copyToClipboard(".$id.");";
echo "<a id='get-link-$id' class='small-button get-link' onclick='$copyToClipboard' data-clipboard-text='myText'><u>Get Link</u></a>";
```

This is done at the top of my page, before my `<script>` tag.

Here's what I have below in my script:

```
new Clipboard(".get-link"); // initialize clipboard elements
$(function() {
    new Clipboard(".get-link"); // initialize clipboard elements
});

function copyToClipboard(id) {
    new Clipboard(".get-link");
    new Clipboard("#get-link-" + id);
    $("#get-link-" + id).text("Copied!");
    setTimeout(function(){ $("#get-link-" + id).text("Get Link"); }, 2000);
}
```

I was redundantly using `new Clipboard(".get-link");` in an effort to make it work.

All this code does is copy the link to the clipboard, then change the text for 2 seconds, then change it back.

#### The problem

It only copies the link to the clipboard after the *second* click on the `a` tag. I can't figure out why.

#### Edit

For some reason, [this JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mikeyaworski/j8yLssy9/1/) shows my code working. Not sure why it doesn't work on my website.

Comment: I sufferd this problem too.... i have not good solution but it works on click where u call the function add trigger..or try with id

Comment: @ManinderpreetSingh The target/trigger approach didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I'm suffering the same thing.. works in fiddle, but not in my website.

Comment: @wonza Unfortunately not. It seems to be an issue on their end.

Comment: Do you have SiteCatalyst on your site? Or any other event tracking code? I just realized this is what's causing the issue for me.. not quite sure how to solve it yet, as we need tracking on the page still

Comment: I was able to solve this by changing my <a> to a <div> as SC doesn't have events on these specifically. I styled up my div and it works perfectly now.. no more second click

Comment: @wonza I might have some libraries screwing this up, so I'll look into that. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not using document ready? Here is working solution for more links:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    new Clipboard(".get-link"); // initialize clipboard elements
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j8yLssy9/11/

Comment: `$(function () {});` is the same as `$(document).ready(function () {});`